# Understanding PHP dateTime object

Tags: php, datetime

I run an automated process via PHP cron job every day which generates a report for a number of months.  The date generation section of the code is below with a bit of hard coding for simplicity.

On the last day of the month it appears to repeat the months; i.e., rather than a series of from-to date pairs that make sense, I get the same date pairs repeated. All I can think of is that I'm doing something in the start and end count calculations that's only an issue on the last day of a month.

Results expected are:

```
From 2013-10-01 to 2013-10-31
From 2013-11-01 to 2013-11-30
...
From 2016-09-01 to 2016-09-30
```

The results I get when running the report on the last day of the month are a bit random.  Here are the dates produced on 31/05 (note that only the TO date is displayed for simplicity.  I know the FROM date is the first of the relevant month because the report data is correct).

```
31/10/2013 
31/10/2013
31/12/2013 
31/12/2013 
31/01/2014 
31/03/2014
31/03/2014 
31/05/2014 
31/05/2014 
31/07/2014 
31/07/2014 
31/08/2014
31/10/2014 
31/10/2014 
31/12/2014 
31/12/2014 
31/01/2015 
31/03/2015
31/03/2015 
31/05/2015 
31/05/2015
31/07/2015
31/07/2015
31/08/2015
31/10/2015
31/10/2015
31/12/2015 
31/12/2015 
31/01/2016 
31/03/2016
31/03/2016
31/05/2016 
31/05/2016 
31/07/2016
31/07/2016
31/08/2016
31/10/2016
```

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$reportBegin = new DateTime("2013-10-01"); // start of report
$reportEnd   = new DateTime("2016-09-01"); // end of report
$nowRef      = new DateTime();
$startCount = (($nowRef->diff($reportBegin)->m) + ($nowRef->diff($reportBegin)->y*12)) * -1; // int * -1 to make neg
$endCount   = (($nowRef->diff($reportEnd)->m)   + ($nowRef->diff($reportEnd)  ->y*12)) + 1;  // int and add 1

    $count = $startCount;   

    // do all months
    while($count <= $endCount){

    $from = date('Y-m-1', strtotime("$count months"));
    $to   = date('Y-m-t', strtotime($from));


        print ("From $from to $to<br />");


    $count++;
    } // done all months
?>
```

Can anyone give me a steer?  I'm not really sure how to test it.

Edit:  The reason I'm mixing `DateTime()` and `date()` is because in production, there's a section of code that in some environments replaces the `DateTime()` section.  This replacement code sets `$startCount` and `$endCount` as integers.

Comment: Why are you mixing DateTime() with date() and strtotime()? Also can you show an example of what results you are getting and what results you are expecting?

Comment: I should have been clearer, sorry.  The DateTime() code is there purely to produce a number of months back, and a number of months forward, based on the hardcoded dates you can see.  The production code has another section where the number of months back and forward are simply stated as integers.  This is because in some environments the scheduled report runs in a different way.  I'll update my question.

Comment: Still gonna need to see the results you are getting and what results you are expecting

Comment: Edited question to add expected results, I'll have to dig around to find the precise incorrect results, will add ASAP.

Comment: This seems to work for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/j0GYpz

Comment: Yes, and it works like this in production too.  Except on the last day of the month!

Comment: [Here's an alternative way of doing it](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Q5PzJw). Let me know if this solves your issue and I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Why the hell you need `$nowRef` at all?

Comment: @cog1 Did my solution help you at all?

Comment: @JohnConde yes, thank you very much.  I haven't had time to get around it properly because I haven't been able to reproduce the problem in test, even if I force the date to the end of a month, so it's hard to say if your suggestion solves it but to answer your question; yes, it's a very helpful approach.

Comment: @JohnConde sorry for the delay.  I've since found the problem is caused by the loop trying to use strtotime to adjust the date when there's a February in the range - adding a month to 31st Jan results in March because there's no 31st Feb.

Your alternative is great, but PHP 5.3.3 doesn't support it and updating isn't possible at present.

So, am testing other options now but I greatly appreciate your ideas.

Comment: @cog1 I posted the code in a PHP5.3 compatible way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PHP5.3 version of the answer in my comment:

```
<?php
$reportBegin = new DateTime("2013-10-01"); // start of report
$reportEnd   = new DateTime("2016-09-01");
$reportEnd->add(new DateInterval('P1M')); // end of report
$interval    = new DateInterval('P1M');
$period      = new DatePeriod($reportBegin, $interval, $reportEnd);

foreach ($period as $month) {
    printf("From %s to %s<br />",
        $month->format('Y-m-01'),
        $month->format('Y-m-t')
    );    
} 
?>
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kz6PER)

PHP 5.4+

```
<?php
$reportBegin = new DateTime("2013-10-01"); // start of report
$reportEnd   = (new DateTime("2016-09-01"))->add(new DateInterval('P1M')); // end of report
$interval    = new DateInterval('P1M');
$period      = new DatePeriod($reportBegin, $interval, $reportEnd);

foreach ($period as $month) {
    printf("From %s to %s<br />",
        $month->format('Y-m-01'),
        $month->format('Y-m-t')
    );    
} 
?>
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Q5PzJw)